# Landscape for personal use

Tags: apt, postgresql, landscape

I am trying to install Landscape Dedicated Server for personal use on a clean Ubuntu 14.04 server from scratch. After adding the ppa-repository and updating apt, I install the thing with apt install landscape-server-quickstart. It all goes well for a while, until:

```
 * Stopping Landscape standalone appserver 1                             [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Landscape standalone async-frontend 1                        [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Landscape standalone job-handler 1                           [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Landscape standalone message-server 1                        [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Landscape standalone pingserver 1                            [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Landscape standalone api 1                                   [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Landscape standalone package-upload 1                        [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Landscape standalone juju-sync 1                             [ OK ] 
WARNING: this may take some time
Site 000-default disabled.
Tuning postgresql for this machine...
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
cp: cannot stat '/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package landscape-server-quickstart (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 landscape-server-quickstart
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried it several times, but it never worked. Does anybody have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the Landscape Server for Personal Use (the Landscape Dedicated Server), I had quite some difficulty getting the QuickStart to work.

I had much more luck with the [Manual Installation](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ManualInstallation15.11) than I did quick-start.  I think that the Manual Installation gets everything working the way it should, while QuickStart isn't a guarantee to make it 100% work.

The instructions change from version to version, slightly, so copying the key instructions into here would be useless - please refer to the link for Manual Installation.

Answer (score 0):

The QuickStart is presumably tested against the latest point release. Try fully updating your clean LTS install first, that will get you from 14.04.0 to 14.04.3.